# Changing only fill or line color in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to change either the line or the fill color with a key, but not both. I've tried adding a dummy word in front of the comma, but it didn't work.

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

PenWidth = int(input("Enter your Penwidth"))
jack = Turtle("turtle")
jack.color("red", "green")
jack.pensize(PenWidth)
jack.speed(0)

 
def blueLine():
    jack.color("blue")
def blueFill():
    jack.color("blue")
def up():
    jack.setheading(90)
    jack.forward(100)



turtle.listen()

turtle.onkey(up, "Up")
turtle.onkey(blueLine, "1")
turtle.onkey(blueFill,"+")

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about problem or share the expected output

Comment: @AshishMJ I want to press 1 to change my turtles line color to blue and I want to press + (shift 1) to make my turtle's fill color blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to change either the line or the fill color with a key, but not
> both.

The simple answer is to invoke `pencolor()` and `fillcolor()` rather than `color()`:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def blueLine():
    jack.pencolor('blue')

def blueFill():
    jack.fillcolor('blue')

def up():
    jack.setheading(90)
    jack.forward(100)

penWidth = int(input("Enter your pen width: "))

screen = Screen()

jack = Turtle('turtle')
jack.color('red', 'green')
jack.pensize(penWidth)
jack.speed('fastest')

screen.onkey(up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(blueLine, '1')
screen.onkey(blueFill, '+')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`turtle.color()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.color) takes in from zero to two arguments.

- If only one argument is provided, the turtle will change both its outline and its fill color to the color provided as the argument.
- If two arguments are provided, the first argument will be the turtle's outline color, and the second will be the turtle's fill color.

But get this:

- If no arguments are provided, the `turtle.color()` method will return the turtle's current colors in the form of a tuple.

Since your turtle's name is `jack`, `jack.color()[0]` will return the turtle's outline color, and `jack.color()[1]` will return the turtle's fill color.

So simple change your functions:

```
def blueLine():
    jack.color("blue")
def blueFill():
    jack.color("blue")
```

to:

```
def blueLine():
    jack.color("blue", jack.color()[1])
def blueFill():
    jack.color(jack.color()[0], "blue")
```